# 27 ftp server error using ftp appache client in passive mode

Tags: java, ftp

Trying to get list of files from FTP in passive mode using FTP appache client

here is connect

```
public void connect() throws IOException {
    ftp.connect(host, port);
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    if (!ftp.login(login, password)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Failed to login ftp server");
    }
}
```

here is method to get list of files

```
 public List<String> getPaths(String path, String date)  {
        try {
         val listFiles = ftp.listFiles(path);//1 
         val listNames = ftp.listNames(path);//2
    return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and next i call getPaths method in a loop to get file or file names from 1000 + folders

and if i use ftp.listFiles(path) i get exception(one or two times from 1000 + calls)

org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: 27 Entering Passive Mode (10,141,166,68,126,88).

if i use ftp.listNames(path) i didnt get this exception

if i use default Ftp mode (means i remove this ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();)
i didnt get exceptions

but here is problem i cant use active ftp mode and i still need to call ftp.listFiles(path)

what is the problem of this exception and how to fix it

here is logs

```
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (95,167,245,94,129,168)
LIST /out/published/Jamalo-Nenetckii_AO/purchaseNoticeEP/daily
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (95,167,245,94,129,0)
LIST /out/published/Jamalo-Nenetckii_AO/purchaseNoticeIS/daily
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
PASV
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: 27 Entering Passive Mode (10,141,166,68,118,198).
```

webshark trafic capture

[image]

this one send to clien wrong ip address

[image]

Comment: I find it quite strange that the IP in the malformed response is different than the one in the valid responses. Can you capture the traffic (e.g. using Wireshark)?

Comment: yes its rly strange can but its not client side for sure

Comment: add webshark screenshot when error happened

Comment: Do I understand right that the *"27 Entering Passive Mode (10,141,166,68,118,198)"* is not in the capture? Please post [mcve].

Comment: i found who sent 27 Entering Passive Mode (10,141,166,68,118,198) look at second screenshot

Comment: seems like i send request PASV and FTP server lost this package then i resent it and ftp server response that he didnt get previous package and send me response with this strange string "27 Entering Passive Mode (10,141,166,68,118,198). so i think its network issue

Comment: Then you would see similar problems even in commandline/GUI FTP clients. Do you?

Comment: do not know how to do this in GUI - this code do 1000+ request to ftp and i get 1 error , or even no error at all. But think if i will try to fast click on folders in GUI i will get same response